# CSemaphore in MFC C++ doesn't work

Tags: multithreading

I'm trying to create a semaphore for multiple threads, i need to run only one thread at a time. I'm declaring the semaphore in my dialog file

```
ghSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, NULL); // only one thread at once
```

Before i start the tread i call

```
WaitForSingleObject(ghSemaphore, 0L);
```

Before the thread ends i call:

```
ReleaseSemaphore(ghSemaphore, 1, NULL);
```

It starts all treads instead of one tread once. Any idea please ? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you add the code for the dialog class, along with the thread stuff so that we can better diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You say "before i start the thread..(you acquire the semaphore)" - so always in the same (main) thread?
I think, the semaphore restrict its acquisition to only *one thread* (which here would be the main thread), so the acquisition needed to be placed inside the (child) threads, to only allow one of them to run concurrently.

You have to create the single one semaphore in the parent thread and pass a reference to it to the child threads. Once one child thread is released from Wait..() the semaphore blocks concurrent threads until the first one releases the semaphore and some next child thread is allowed to run. However, all child threads do run concurrently until their call of the Wait..().

Btw: Why do you create multiple threads if you actually want only one thread to run at any time (until it terminates)?

Regarding the scope where to create the semaphore: From the info you provided it looks ok to have one single semaphore at application level. However, i would recommend to pass it to the child threads as a parameter at thread start (instead of referring a global variable), so the child threads are independent of the choice of the scope. If you ever need to handle multiple, independent bunches of such child threads, you can easily switch to create one semaphore for each bunch just before they are created (the other option you mentioned). If you create semaphores on the fly, be sure to release it, once all threads have terminated.

So, for now, best create one application-wide semaphore ("global").

Comment: i did that but still all treads run at same time. Should i use CreateSemaphore instead of Csemaphore ? Also where should i declare Csemaphore , inside the tread child or in main ? i tried both ways but none works correctly

Comment: After i start the thread i call: WaitForSingleObject(ghSemaphore, INFINITE); and before the tread ends i call: ReleaseSemaphore(ghSemaphore, 1, NULL);. Now how about the call: HANDLE ghSemaphore = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, NULL);. this one should i call it in main function or at the beginning of application as a global value ? I tried this way and it works but not sure if it is correct